# How to allow Parallel Processing of Events on my entire Axon Application?

Tags: spring-boot, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, axon

I'm using axon-spring-boot-starter 4.0.3 and trying to get Parallel Processing of Events to work so I can scale my application better. From what I understood from reading around is that I can do so by adding the following to my axon configuration

> axon.eventhandling.processors.[name].initialSegmentCount=4
>
> axon.eventhandling.processors.[name].threadCount=2
>
> axon.eventhandling.processors.[name].mode=tracking

Now first is that, is this the only addition I need to make it work? Second, does that mean I need to add this configuration to every Processor? Since the Processor Name is needed for the configuration, or is there a way to apply this configuration to all processors?

Edit: An additional question, following the guide provided on [github](https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-quick-start/blob/master/chat-scaling-out/README.md), they mention deleting the processor from the entry_token. Does that mean all the events will get replayed? If so, is there a way to select which events get replayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to configure your Tracking Event Processors (TEP) through an `application.properties` file, then yes you will have to specify this for every `TrackingEventProcessor` instance you have defined.

However, as of Axon Framework release 4.1 you can register a default configuration, by using the following method:

```
EventProcessingConfigurer#registerTrackingEventProcessorConfiguration(
        Function<Configuration, TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration>
)
```

As you're using Spring Boot, I'd suggest to add an `@Autowired void` method which configures the default `TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration` for you, to segmentize the `TrackingToken` of each TEP and to set up multiple threads per TEP.

---

That's my main answer, but you have a couple of other questions in there to.
So, let's go over them as well:

> Second, does that mean I need to add this configuration to every Processor?

With the above, you have technical split the Event Stream into several "Segments".
This is needed as a TEP **is required** to lay a claim on a `TrackingToken`, and segmentizing a TEP is similar to segmentizing the `TrackingToken`.

Note that this essential splits up the Event Stream. As such, a given TEP thread **will no longer** receive all the events, but just a subset of events.
Depending on what set of events you want your Query Models, you need to think about *how* this segmentation takes place.

Axon Framework for this uses the `SequencingPolicy` (defaults to `SequentialPerAggregatePolicy`), which you can configure through the `EventProcessingConfigurer`. [This](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors#parallel-processing) Reference Guide page also explains this notion by the way.

---

> An additional question, following the guide provided on github, they mention deleting the processor from the entry_token.

Just configuring your TEP to use several segments **will not** automatically adjust the number of segments in you set up. This stems from the fact that the `TrackingToken` for a given TEP will be split up into several tokens, which is work you will have to delegate correctly.

The simple approach to run with multi segments, would be to drop your existing tokens. 
This will indeed replay your events, so you're right on that track.

Note that as of Axon 4.1, the TEP implementation has an API to split/merge its Tracking Tokens (as is written down [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors#splitting-and-merging-tracking-tokens)).
However, this API requires that the given TEP can claim **all** existing Tracking Tokens.
If you are thus running with multiple instances of a given application, those API calls will require delegation among them.
Axon Server however provides a great UI to delegate the splitting and/or merging of Tracking Tokens for each TEP in your set up.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply as always, I have a better understanding how it works now, I'm trying to have one of my EventProcessors(a Saga) to have parallel processing and was using the axoniq api as I felt like the spring configuration isn't enough for my case.  I will include it in the next comment to fit. For the sake of my example I have  1 machine, I want it to have 4 threads and have my events on 4 segments. Also I do not want to replay any event so I added the andInitialTrackingToken(StreamableMessageSource::createHeadToken). I ran the below code but nothing changed

Comment: @Autowired
    public void configureProcessor(Configurer configurer) {
        configurer.eventProcessing().registerTrackingEventProcessor("test",
                        c -> c.eventStore(),
                        c -> c.getComponent(
                                TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration.class,
                                () -> TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration.forParallelProcessing(3).andInitialSegmentsCount(3).andInitialTrackingToken(StreamableMessageSource::createHeadToken)
                        )
                );
    }

Comment: What you have effectively done there is set up a `TrackingEventProcessor` with  the Processing Group `test`, using the `EventStore` as it's source and you provided it a config with 3 threads, 3 token segments and a token starting at the head. I however do not see how this configuration is tied to your Saga instance at the moment. To achieve this, you need to mark you Saga implementation you want to parallelize with the `@ProcessingGroup({insert-group-name})` annotation. The value set in the processing group annotation should mirror the name of your TEP for it to be active.

Comment: I said test for the sake of giving an example, but from what I understood that Sagas don't need the annotation @ProcessingGroup as the group name will be the same one as the name of the Saga. Thus in my code instead of test I have the name of the Saga, does this not work in this case? Should I explicitly add the annotation to my saga?

Comment: The default processing group name Axon gives to a Saga is `{saga-class-name}Processor`. Thus, if you've used that as the `name` when configuring the TEP, I would've assumed this to work.

If this does not solve your problem, it might warrant an update to the original question you've posted. That way it's easier to track for other readers.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if I should put a different question or edit the current one, since the spring boot configuration (by adding the field to my properties file) worked properly. But the one using the api isnt working (yes I test in here represent {saga-class-name}Processor in my case)

Comment: Good point...I think your gut is right in setting up a new question for this issue.

Comment: I added the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594428/how-to-enable-parallel-processing-for-a-processing-group-using-the-axon-api) if you can check it